# are any two vector spaces with the same (infinite) dimension isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Is it true that any 2 vector spaces with the same (infinite) dimension are isomorphic? I think that it is true, since we can build a mapping from $V$ to $\mathbb{F}^{N}$ where the cardinality of $N$ is the dimension of the vector space - where by $\mathbb{F}^{N}$ I mean the subset of the full cartesian product - where each element contains only finite non zero coordinates?

Comment: There are many kinds of infinities ... Not all infinite sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: In other words: By definition, the dimension is the cardinality of a basis - and same cardinality implies bijection between bases and immediately suggests an isomorphism of the spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is quite correct.

Comment: @ Rob Arthan ... can you please enplane how to the above result..

Comment: Is there any simplest way to prove for infinite dim case?