# Euclidean space as a different dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra

Clearly $ \mathbb{R}^{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is vector space of dimension $n$ under addition and scalar multiplication as component wise addition and scalar multiplication . But i am trying to define $ \mathbb{R}^{n}(\mathbb{R})$  as a vector space that is not in the usual sense as above i.e. not component wise addition and scalar multiplication so that it is of dimension different from $n$.For example $ \mathbb{R}^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ as a vector space of dimension different from $2$, $ \mathbb{R}^{3}(\mathbb{R})$ as vector space of dimension different from $3$. One thing is clear by using cardinal numbers $ \mathbb{R}^{n}(\mathbb{R})$ can not be of infinite dimension. Is it possible to define $ \mathbb{R}^{n}(\mathbb{R})$ as a vector space of dimension different from $n$. If possible please explane. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well... you could merge them pair-wise and make a smaller complex vector field.

Comment: no i am trying real vector space...

Comment: What does the notation $\Bbb R^2(\Bbb R)$ mean? (P.S.: Regarding your recently-deleted question: we *were* trying to understand you, but none of us was sure what your notation meant, hence all our clarifying questions. I'm sorry some people saw fit to simply downvote without comment.)

Comment: @CameronBuie    Generally the notation  $V(\mathbb{F})$ is for vector space $V$ over the field $\mathbb{F}.$

Comment: and i think it is common in whole linear algebra...

Comment: @CameronBuie i used the result that if $V(\mathbb{F})=N$ then $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}^{N}$ ....http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547314/are-any-two-vector-spaces-with-the-same-infinite-dimension-isomorphic?rq=1

Comment: Now if $\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$ is a vector space then certainly its dimension is infinite and smallest infinite cardinal number is $\aleph_{0}$ . Now $|\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{Z}_{3}|^{\aleph_{0}}>|\mathbb{Q}|$ a contradiction...

Comment: Ah, so you were trying to determine if we could define appropriate operations to make $\Bbb Q$ a vector space over $\Bbb Z_3$? *Now* I understand. Your approach is simple and elegant. Nicely done!

Comment: Ok thanks for understanding my approach....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be of a different dimension under the same field, then clearly you'll need to change the definition of the addition and/or scalar multiplication. One way to do this is to let $\phi : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be any bijection (one exists because they have the same cardinality), where $m \neq n$, then define new addition $\oplus$ and new scalar multiplication $\odot$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by conjugation:
\begin{align}
x \oplus y &:= \phi^{-1}(\phi(x) + \phi(y)) \\
\lambda \odot x &:= \phi^{-1}(\lambda \phi(x)).
\end{align}
Then one can easily check that $\phi$ becomes, by design, an isomorphism between $\mathbb{R^n}(\mathbb{R}, \oplus, \odot)$ and $\mathbb{R}^m(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$, hence they are of the same dimension $m$.

Comment: in am trying to prove vector space properties....clearly under new addition Abelian group  properties are satisfied....

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ *is* a vector space under $\oplus$, $\odot$. Check the axioms!

Comment: Yes all  are satisfied...i checked it....Thanks a lot...

Comment: Its means that any finite dimensional  vector space of dim n  can be changed so that it become m{different from n} dimensional vector space. Am i right?

Comment: So long as you have an infinite scalar field, then yes, exactly. That's why, when studying spaces, we typically require more preserved structure than raw cardinality.

Comment: ok..thanks for nicely explanation ..

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that, at least not continuously.

In essence, you want $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be isomorphous to another real vector space $\mathbb{R}^m$. Recall that $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have the same cardinality (continuum), but there is no *continuous* map between them (although you can interleave digits or use other funny tricks).

Yu can take a subspace (projection), or immerse into a bigger vector space, but thats not a 1-to-1 mapping. An isomorphism of vector spaces implies that their dimensions are the same.

Comment: Any linear transformation will be continuous map...

Comment: But there are no bijective linear transformations between spaces of different dimensions.

Comment: Yes there is no bijection linear map....but if we define R^n with different dimension say m, clearly there is no bijection between R^n and R^m..

Comment: I think there is no use of this fact...

Comment: If you want to define R^n to have a dimension R^m, there must be a mapping that will *make* it R^m. In the sense that you have a function that takes a n-dimensional vector and returns a vector with dimension m. Either that, or you stated your question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, though I suspect not in any "sensible" way.  Here is an example, I am sure that you can generalise it.

We know from set theory considerations that there exists a bijection $\phi$ from $\def\R{{\Bbb R}}\R^2$ to $\R^3$.  Define operations on $\R^3$ as follows:
$$x\oplus y=f(f^{-1}(x)+f^{-1}(y))\ ,\quad
  \lambda\otimes x=f(\lambda f^{-1}(x))\ ,$$
where the addition and scalar multiplication in $\R^2$ are standard.  Then it is not hard to check that $\R^3$ is a real vector space with respect to the operations $\oplus$ and $\otimes$, and that it is isomorphic to the standard space $\R^2$.  Therefore $\R^3$ with these operations has dimension $2$.

Comment: Its means that any finite dimensional vector space of dim n can be changed so that it become m{different from n} dimensional vector space. Am i right?